# Report Game Center achievements too frequently?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center, achievements

I'm developing a game with cocos2d about a jumping frog. In this game the jumping action is VERY common (from 25 to 60 times per level depending on the difficult). I'm integrating the game with Game Center and I would like to add several achievements about the number of jumps (for example: "Novice jumper: You have jumped 200 times", "Medium jumper: You have jumped 1000 times"... and so on)

The problem is that I think that a "call" to Game Center to update number of jumps every jump may be too much and it could make the app to be slowly or make it fail due to make many calls to "reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler" method, but it is the only way I know to show the achievement when it is unlocked (I mean, for example, to show the achievement unlocked pop-up with the 200th jump)

Is this really a problem? Or it's normal to update achievements frequently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about changing the frequency of updates? Instead of updating every jump, update every 10/25/n jumps instead. Or update at the end of the level.

Comment: displaying that view at the top when the game end doesn't really make sense for player. I would just save number of jumps in the local variable and then check if jumps == 100 else if etc and if any of these is true then call outside method where game center will actually update scores ([self update gameCenter];

Comment: It's a good question, and I'm disappointed that no one didn't answer it in 10 years :|